# Как правильно выбрать родительскую тему?

Tags: android, style

В моем приложении определены два xml файла styles.xml определяющие тему приложения, различающихся для разных версий api.
В одном случае это `values-v21/styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_red</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/gray</item>

        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/soothing_blue</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/BeatBoxButton</item>

    </style>

    <style name="BeatBoxButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Material.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_beat_box</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Который работает корректно (проверял на android 6) и где для кнопок применяется определяемая мной кастомизированная buttonStyle

и в другом случае это `values/styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_red</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/gray</item>

        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/soothing_blue</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/BeatBoxButton</item>

    </style>

    <style name="BeatBoxButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_beat_box</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

который используется в случае api < 21 (проверял на android 4.4.2).
Проблема в том что для кнопок стиль не меняется и они отображаются со стандартным отображением. Если задать непосредственно в файле отвечающим за отображение кнопки `android:background="@drawable/button_beat_box"` то требуемые параметры применяются.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема - не хочется создавать отдельный файл layout-21 так как это противоречит работе со стилями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего дело в том, что основная тема у вас из библиотеки поддержки, а тема кнопки для API<21 из `Holo`. Попробуйте вот эту тему родительской для стиля диалога:

```
Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button
```

Либо попробуйте убрать пространство имён `android` перед именем в стилях до 21 апи:

```
<item name="buttonStyle">@style/BeatBoxButton</item>
```